# Android studio can not update with a warning

Tags: android

When the downloading is finish,it comes a warning:"The Android SDK folder can no longer be inside the application folder.Please move it to a different location such as your home folder.When the IDE restart it will prompt you to enter the new location......"
And I restart it and choose a different loaction,but it didn't work.

Comment: move the sdk folder to elsewhere from your current installation directory. Then hit retry, give the new path when asked by android studio at startup after update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "The Android SDK folder can no longer be inside the application
>   folder.Please move it to a different location such as your home
>   folder.When the IDE restart it will prompt you to enter the new
>   location"

Open the folder where you put your android studio, on Mac is (`Applications/Android\ Studio.app/`) and on Windows is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\android-studio\sdk`, and move the `sdk` folder you find inside in another location. After you moved it in another location, press the retry button.

Answer (score 2):

Cut **sdk** folder from (This is default location, you may have installed it somewhere else)

> C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio

and paste it somewhere else then try to update.

Once it get updated then set the path your sdk in studio.

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Tools Project Site](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0814inbetachannel)

> To proceed, you should open up a file explorer or finder window, go to
>   the Android Studio installation (e.g. /Applications/Android
>   Studio.app) and move the sdk/ folder over to a different location,
>   such as your home directory. Once done, press Retry to finish
>   installing the patch. The reason this is necessary is two-fold: First,
>   we have made a lot of improvements to make the patch updater more
>   accurate, and in order for installation signatures to match, you
>   cannot have non-application folders inside the application directory.
>   Second, placing the SDK folder inside the application directory was
>   probably not a good idea to begin with: this folder should typically
>   be writable and in a directory with a lot of extra diskspace, such
>   that users can easily download and install additional libraries,
>   system images and so on. We are doing some work on the installer side
>   to make this easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Grab sdk folder from

C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk

and paste it somewhere else like C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio
and start the update.
Then it will ask you to put the path. and its done